# How do I read 2 particular columns from a txt file in Java?

Tags: java, regex, hashmap, delimiter, file-handling

How do I read 2 particular column(1st column and 3rd Column) from a txt file. The main problem is that the columns are separated by different delimiters(I want to ignore the 2nd column in which (base 16) is written). Also how do I skip the column headings.
The txt file looks as follows:

```
IOU/AB-L                                                    Organization                                 
company_id                                                  Organization                                 
                                                            Address                                      

D0-AB-DB   (hex)             Ahenhen ViewAt Technology Co.,Ltd. 
D0ABDB     (base 16)         Ahenhen ViewAt Technology Co.,Ltd. 
                             9A,Microprofit,6th Gaoxin South Road, High-Tech 
                             Industrial Park, Nanshan, henzhen.
                             henzhen  guangdong  51867
                             DN

42-05-F5   (hex)            Integrated Technology (Malaysia) Sdn. Bhd.
4205F5     (base 16)        Integrated Technology (Malaysia) Sdn. Bhd.
                            Phase 1, Bayan Aepas FIZ
                            Bayan Lepas  Penang  11923
                            NY
```

I was trying with the following piece of code. But its not working.

```
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split("   ", 3);
        if (parts.length >= 3) {
            String key = parts[0];
            String value = parts[2];
            System.out.println("Key value pair is " + key + "   " + value);
            map.put(key, value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("ignoring line: " + line);
        }
    }
```

So Basically I want to read `D0-AB-DB` and `Ahenhen ViewAt Technology Co.,Ltd.` in 1st line and after that I want to read `42-05-F5` and `Integrated Technology (Malaysia) Sdn. Bhd.` in 2nd line.

What regular expression should I use in this case. A sample code would be helpful.

Thanx in Advance!!

Comment: Please edit your question and post a minimal representation of the actual problem.

Comment: Give at least what you expect as result from your input (not clear what you want).

Comment: Basically I want to read `D0-AB-DB` and `Ahenhen ViewAt Technology Co.,Ltd.` in 1st line and after that I want to read `42-05-F5` and `Integrated Technology (Malaysia) Sdn. Bhd.` in 2nd line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write your while loop as follows:

```java
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] parts = line.split("\\((hex)\\)", 3);

        if (parts.length >= 2) {
            String key = parts[0].trim();
            String value = parts[1].trim();
            System.out.println("Key value pair is :" + key + "   " + value);
            map.put(key, value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("ignoring line: " + line);
        }
    }
```